# log4j ReflectionUtil.getCallerClass() consuming way too much CPU time

Tags: java, slf4j, log4j2

I did some performance analysis of my app and discovered that the method `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil.getCallerClass()`
of the log4j framework consumes about half the cpu time of my application.

Is this a known problem? If so what can be done to address this issue?

Btw. I'm running Java8, log4j 2.3 and slf4j 1.7

The following is a screenshot from the VisualVM output

[image: CPU Time Hotspots]

Comment: Are you sure it is cause? did you try to comment this out see if it goes back to normal?

Comment: I am not 100pc sure, all the info I have is from the visual vm output (added a screenshot). what do you mean by commenting out, the getCallerClass() method in the ReflectionUtil class or my log statements?

Comment: I mean your log statement. you can just comment it out entirely see if it goes back to normal. or you may to go https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-api/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ReflectionUtil.java have a look at source code. usually, loop consumes CPU, you may find something else. This is all I can help  :)

Comment: If you are using a PatternLayout in your Log4j configuration, you may want to read this: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#LocationInformation: some fields like %C, %L, %F, or others are known too have very poor performances (because a full thread stack trace is generated for each call).